# Breaking items in a list into lists in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to make something that goes over my folders and find duplicates. That said, files cant have identical names, so the first part I made is to go over the folder and append a list of folders. Then I want to break the items in the list into lists and compare each other and find high similarities. I'm quite stuck with the 2nd part and don't know how to approach. If anyone can shed some light it'd be great, thanks!

```
import os

path = input("Where you want to look?")

myFolder = list()
print("Here's your folders:")
for dirname in os.listdir(path):
    f = os.path.join(path,dirname)
    if os.path.isdir(f):
        myFolder.append(f)

print("\n".join(myFolder))
print(len(myFolder), "folders found!")
```

I'm thinking about creating a dictionary of lists, each list is a folder name broken down letter by letter

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _"break the items in the list into lists and compare each other and find high similarities."_ It would help if you show an example input and expected output

Comment: If you just want to find duplicates, there's [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes).

Comment: let's say I have a file named file.txt, then there's file(1).txt with identical texts in it. My approach is to iterate through the folder, return a list, break the list of items into ["f", "i", "l", "e"] and ["f", "i", "l", "e", "(", "1", ")"]  then compare each list to find highly similar named files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to use the library `pathlib`, since `os` is a bit outdated for file exploring.
Here's how you can do what you want:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder_path = Path(input("Where you want to look?"))
folder_content = [file_or_dir for file_or_dir in folder_path.iterdir() if file_or_dir.is_file()]

# folder_content's code is the equivalent of:
folder_content = []
for file_or_dir in folder_path.iterdir(): # listing the files of folder_path
    if file_or_dir.is_file(): # checking if file_or_dir is a file or not
        folder_content.append(file_or_dir) # if it is, we add it to the list folder_content

# Then we check for duplicates
names_list = [file.name for file in folder_content] # We make a list that contains all of the names

for name in names_list:
    if names_list.count(name) > 1: # if find more than one same name in the names_list
        print(f'Name "{name}" found more than one time !!!')
```